# Strange behaviour of a uniform integer variable using GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm coding a graphic engine using OpenGL + GLSL shaders. Currently, I manage several lights in my scene (per-pixel lighting mode). So, I have a loop to access to the properties of all lights in the scene for each pixel. If I put the light count value directly in the loop condition there's not problem but if I want to do this job in a dynamic way by sending an integer uniform variable from my C++ code it does not work. But I checked in the fragment shader the value of the variable and this one is correct. In my example just below, my light list has a size of 1.

Here's my c++ code :

```
ShaderProgram *program = (*Ite).second->getShaderProgram();

program->bind();

program->setUniform("spotCount", (int)this->m_Scene->getLightList().size()); //1 in my example
```

My vertex shader code :

```
#version 400

layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 VertexTexture;

uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 MVP;

out vec3 VPosition;
out vec3 VNormal;
out vec2 VTexCoords;

void main(void)
{
    VTexCoords = VertexTexture;
    VNormal = normalize(NormalMatrix * VertexNormal);
    VPosition = vec3(ModelViewMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0f));
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0f);
}
```

And finally, my fragment shader code :

```
#version 400

in vec3 Position;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoords;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D Tex1;
uniform int spotCount;

struct Light
{
    vec4 Position;
    vec3 La, Ld, Ls;
};

uniform Light LightInfos[1];

struct Material
{
    vec3 Ka, Kd, Ks, Ke;
    float Shininess;
};

uniform Material MaterialInfos;

vec3 ADS_Phong_Shading(int idx, vec3 n, vec3 s)
{
    vec3 v = normalize(vec3(-Position));
    vec3 h = normalize(v + s);

    vec3 Ambient = LightInfos[idx].La * MaterialInfos.Ka;
    vec3 Diffuse = LightInfos[idx].Ld * MaterialInfos.Kd * max(dot(s, n), 0.0f);
    vec3 Specular = LightInfos[idx].Ls * MaterialInfos.Ks * pow(max(dot(h, n), 0.0f), MaterialInfos.Shininess);
    vec3 Emissive = MaterialInfos.Ke;

    return (Ambient + Diffuse + Specular + Emissive);
}

void main(void)
{
    vec4 TexColor = texture(Tex1, TexCoords);
    vec3 LightIntensity = vec3(0.0f);
    vec3 position = vec3(0.0f);

    if (spotCount == 1) { //Here a stupid condition proving that spotCount = 1

    for (int idx = 0; idx < spotCount; idx++)
    {
        vec3 tnorm = (gl_FrontFacing ? -normalize(Normal) : normalize(Normal));
        if (LightInfos[idx].Position.w == 0.0f)
            position = normalize(vec3(LightInfos[idx].Position));
        else if (LightInfos[idx].Position.w == 1.0f)
        {
            position = normalize(vec3(LightInfos[idx].Position) - Position);
        }
        LightIntensity += ADS_Phong_Shading(idx, -tnorm, position);
    }

    }

    if (TexColor != 0)
        FragColor = vec4(LightIntensity, 1.0f) * TexColor;
    else
        FragColor = vec4(LightIntensity, 1.0f);
}
```

In the fragment shader code if I replace the code :

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < spotCount; idx++)
```

By the following code :

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < 1; idx++)
```

my scene is correctly displayed.

Here's a picture if I use the instruction : for (int idx = 0; idx < spotCount; idx++) (NOT CORRECT) -> spotCount == 1 :

[image]

And with the instruction for (int idx = 0; idx < 1; idx++) (CORRECT) :

[image]

In conclusion I have the same number of iteration for the two cases but not the same result.

Does anyone can help me ? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you making any assumptions anywhere about the "uniform location" of your uniforms? A lot of GLSL compilers will not assign a uniform a location unless it is referenced somewhere in the shader (determined after linking each stage). When you do reference this uniform, it may be changing the uniform location of other uniforms. Obviously if you always make a point of querying the uniform location after linking your shaders, this should not matter, but if you ever assume that some uniform is going to be at a certain location this could be your problem.

Comment: some operations are not allowed with uniforms... try to copy it to local variable and use it instead. maybe it helps. int N; N=spotCount;  for (int idx=0;idx<N;idx++) ....